# 5-party Ring Signatures still being implicatory for sender?

Tags: privacy, ringsize, transactions

Why are 5-party ring signatures enough for privacy? I don't understand how even if I get everything else right privacy-wise, I can still be connected to a transaction and potentially implicated in something to the tune of a 1/5 chance I was involved. Say there was some other real-life clue that would never be enough on its own, but could be damning enough if combined with the knowledge that I was at least a potential signer of that transaction? Hoping I'm just underestimating one-time stealth addresses or something, because it seems like all the introductory material seems to gloss over this as being fine.

Answer (score 3):

Privacy concerns related to ring size are most significant in cases where [an exchange or person that gave you the output you are spending knows you control it and is aware of your identity](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/3909/7). Significantly [reducing the statistical likelihood of a TX being connected to you](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4568/7) in the above situation is not difficult using the current default ring size:

> Can you tell that those funds actually came from the TX you sent to me 5 hops ago? Probability would be (1/N)^5 that it came from me. For ringsize 5, that's 0.0000032% chance. Just one of many possibilities, without any way of knowing which one is the real trail.

[Monero Research Lab](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monero-research-lab) continues to evaluate the [ring size](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1673) issue. Minimum ring size will be increased in the future. However, because of the way ring size currently impacts tx size, it is likely that [bulletproofs](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/6781/7) will be implemented before or in conjunction with any major adjustment to the minimum ring size:

> Bulletproofs offer substantial improvements when using multiple outputs. With current Monero range proof technology, transaction sizes scale mostly linearly depending on the number of outputs (eg: 1 output = 7kB, 2 outputs = 13kB). With bulletproofs, these scale logarithmically instead (eg: 1 output = 2kB, 2 outputs = 2.5kB).